# Parquet: NULL, or zero-length array?

Tags: hive, avro, parquet

I'm designing a schema in Avro that will ultimately become the schema for a Parquet file to be queried by Hive.

There are several instances where I've got a nested column as an array of type , and the parent record may have zero or more . To use a more concrete example, let's say that I have a Person record, with a Children field. A Person can have zero or more children.

Are there any persuasive arguments on whether the Children field should be an array that can have zero items, or should instead be defined as a union of [null, array]?

That is, if there are zero children, should I use NULL, or should I use a zero-length array?

This early in my learning curve it appears to be a philosophical choice. But I don't know what I don't know, and so I'm hoping the community can share their insights based on experience that I don't have: should this be a NULLable column, or simply an array that could have zero elements in it?